# ActionMethodSelectorAttribute equivalent in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there a Web API equivalent to the MVC `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`?

My specific purpose is this:  I have, for example, a `ResourceController` and when I `POST` to the controller, I'd like to be able to receive a single resource (`Resource`) or a list (`IEnumerable<Resource>`).

I was hoping creating two methods with different parameters would cause the deserialization process to do some evaluation but this doesn't seem to be the case (and frankly, I don't think it's efficiently realistic with the combination of content negotiation and the fact that many data formats, like JSON, make it difficult to infer the data type).  So I originally had:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Resource resource) {...}

public HttpResponseMessage Post(IEnumerable<Resource> resources) {...}
```

...but this gets the "multiple actions" error.  So I investigated how to annotate my methods and came across `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` but also discovered this is only for MVC routing and not Web API.

So... without requiring a different path for POSTing multiple resources vs. one (which isn't the end of the world), what would I do to differentiate?

My thoughts along the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` were to require a query parameter specifying multiple, which I suppose is no different than a different path.  So, I think I just eliminated my current need to do this, but I would still like to know if there is an equivalent `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` for Web API :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a replacement for that method (there is an `IActionMethodSelector` interface but it is internal to the DLL). One option (although it seems like it might be overdoing it) is to overload the `IHttpActionSelector` implementation that is used.

But changing gears slightly, why not always expect an `IEnumerable<Resource>`? My first guess is that the collection method (that takes `IEnumerable<Resource>`) would simply loop and call the single value (just `Resource`) function?

Comment: I've actually been considering just having the `IEnumerable<Resource>` but most use cases for this method will be a single resource.  I'm only introducing the multi-resource POST for some potential batch operations.  Personally, when my main use case requires a single object but I'm always required to pass in a list, I get annoyed.  A minor thing, but code looks cleaner when you don't have extraneous `new [] { myResource }` all over the place.  I'm also considering leaving the HTTP API layer as only the `IEnumerable<Resource>` & put overloads in the wrapper(s) currently C#).

Comment: Ha, and interpret "code looks cleaner" not just as an OCD symptom but also better maintainability, easier to understand, etc. :)

Comment: I can see what you mean about the code API aspect being a little strange with only accepting a collection of items. I wonder if a `params` argument would work in the action?